# .net core get certificate from store runs different from framework

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have already writen dll , it's works in .Net Framework project, but gives error on .Net Core Rest Api. In .Net core  it privatekey class different from .Net Framework. Can I solve problem without rewriting this library? It's 3rd party library and I must not change it. If it's not possible then i need a solution with minimum changes.

For `.Net Core` it has `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng`
but for `.Net Framework` it has `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider`

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore(
          string issuer,
          string serialNumber)
        {
            X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in x509Store.Certificates)
            {
                if (certificate.Issuer == issuer && certificate.SerialNumber.ToLower() == serialNumber.ToLower())
                    return certificate;
            }
            return (X509Certificate2)null;
        }
```

[image]

For this reason occurs error on this line

```
CryptoLib.UpgradeCsp((RSACryptoServiceProvider)signingCert.PrivateKey);
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it a concern? It doesn’t mean the private key is different, but just how it is “deserialized”.

Comment: I have already writen dll , it's works in .Net Framework project, but gives error on .Net Core Rest Api. And reason for error starts here

Comment: Where is the connection with the posted code?

Comment: CryptoLib.UpgradeCsp((RSACryptoServiceProvider)signingCert.PrivateKey);

Comment: Whatever is doing the hard cast like that won’t work on Core, it all need to change, or you’ll need to stop using it.